# better way for angular to mock the server response data?

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I am currently working on a *component library* which will depend on different servers out there.

I am creating a demo application to use the component library, so all the requests can be caught easily with [`interceptors`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) to mock the server response as this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpclient-interceptor-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) I created.

#### Restrictions

- components themselves will handle the request (components user will just pass in critical arguments);
- no modifications allowed to the components library;

#### Reality

- servers sometimes can be unreachable;
- making a demo application to present how to use the components actually doesn't require the actual interaction with servers most of the time;

But still I am curious about: are there other ways to handle this kind of cases?

*Most of the time, I heard it that interceptors used to **modify** request/response(or cache sometimes) instead of mocking*.

Thank you :)

Comment: Yes, interceptors purpose is to modify request and handle the response for different purpose like attaching token, handling errors. What actually you want to achieve? LIke you need to mock data from server?

Answer (score 2):

You can install `json-server` and then just use the mock data from it.

```
npm install -g json-server
```

Create a `db.json` file with some data

```
{
  "posts": [
    { "id": 1, "title": "json-server", "author": "typicode" }
  ],
  "comments": [
    { "id": 1, "body": "some comment", "postId": 1 }
  ],
  "profile": { "name": "typicode" }
}
```

Start JSON Server

```
json-server --watch db.json
```

Now if you go to http://localhost:3000/posts/1, you'll get

```
{ "id": 1, "title": "json-server", "author": "typicode" }
```

Refer: https://github.com/typicode/json-server

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you can use JSON data. You can save your JSON data in a file and intercept your request at Interceptors and send the mock data from the file like below.

```
@Injectable()
export class SampleInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const httpRequest = new HttpRequest(
      <any>request.method,
      "./../../assets/sample.json"
    );
    request = Object.assign(request, httpRequest);
    request = request.clone();
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Comment: yes because of this you don't have to make the request to the server. You just will retrieve data from your local JSON file that you create. That Jason file will have your mocked data.

Comment: I think I got your point. If I am right your call will be dynamic like the post id and params. But in that case, also you are trying to mock the expected data, right? So for each different request, you can create a separate file and have expected mock data over there. I can tell this much on your explained scenario.

Comment: just `http.get(local_path)` won't solve the issue since it will require modifications in the component library request method. I am more thinking of AOP method to let the library alone (without being touched)

Comment: @Hearen have a look on my edited answer if it helps.

Comment: A good point to mutate the `HttpRequest` but actually that's what I tried using `require(local_file_path)` and `of(MOCK_DATA)` directly. Thanks for the help :)